# What is the most recent web services version from netsuite?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, netsuite

I am trying to log in via the WSDL to a NetSuite sandbox where I already have admin rights and can log in using the GUI. I am wondering what is the most recent web services version for NetSuite? I have found https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2013_2_0/netsuite.wsdl and I am wondering if this is the most recent (or best) one to use.

Comment: Here is a list of all the WSDL URLs: https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2017/05/netsuite-suitetalk-wsdl-urls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [NetSuite SuiteTalk Documentation](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-documentation.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is 2015.1, not 2014.2 as mentioned in the SuiteTalk Documentation.

Here's a link to the [2015.1 WSDL](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2015_1_0/netsuite.wsdl).

Comment: Thank you; the Suite Talk Documentation link does state 2015.1 for the WSDL.

Comment: It's now up to 2016.2 https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_2_0/netsuite.wsdl